# ssh-add on compute engine ubuntu vm for out going

Tags: ubuntu, ssh-keys, google-compute-engine

I have an `id_rsa` key that I use to connect via scp to a remote server that I've moved to my Ubuntu GCE. I have dropped the key (`id_rsa`) into main user `.ssh` folder, chmod 600 but `ssh-add` won't pick it up.

`sftp -v -o 'IdentityFile2 id_rsa' user@domain` gives me:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/my_user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to remotesite.com [66.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

`ssh-add id_rsa`:

```
SSH_AGENT_FAILURE
Could not add identity: id_rsa
```

I got my remote IDE and SSH clients working to connect to my server and like the security and am somewhat paranoid to start jacking with the `sshd_conf` file in case I open a door that shouldn't be open or mess with the keys and connections that are working now. Any pointers?

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the key file?  Where did you move the key from (what os)?  Based on the ssh-add error, I'm betting some formatting occured when it was xfered.  Some kind of encoding / compression.. it'll mess that stuff up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was tarred up from a CENTOS machine, I copied it without compressing and still same messages.